# String distance equations for fuzzy-matching person names

Tags: similarities, jaccard-similarity

A reproducible example with a small bit of R code is [available in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894177/fuzzy-left-join-person-full-names-in-r-handling-tricky-edge-cases-cannot-inst) (link so I dont need to re-type out the code). The `fuzzytext` library in R has the following available string methods `c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram", "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex")`. Our use case is matching (left-joining) basketball player names from 2 different sources. From the stackoverflow post, we have the following concerns to account for when string matching names:

- The left join shouldn't get mixed up by long / short names. `Michael Gadson` is clearly `Mike Gadson`, not one of the other Mike names in the dataset with a different last name.
- The left join shouldn't get mixed up by reversed names. `Ricky Smith` is `Rick Smith`, he is not `Smith Rickie`.
- The left join shouldn't get mixed up by `III`, `Jr.`, etc. suffix to names, or by extra spaces or symbols: eg. `De Andre'` vs `DeAndre`)
- Certain players (e.g. `Johnny Williams`) in the left-hand-side dataframe have no match in the right-side table. To catch this, we'll need to rely on a properly selected `max_dist` value.

A 5th concern is avoiding duplicates in the code (we want only 1 row for each person in the left-hand-side dataframe), however this is handled with the `groupby(fullName) %>% filter(dist == min(dist) | is.na(dist))` in the code.

Our question is then: given these concerns, what is a good method and max distance to use for this left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point about long / short names is slightly difficult to do with edit distance alone. A two stage profess may work: use edit distances with a low maximum edit distance (to minimize false positives) first and then manually fix any remaining non-matches.

I would try the Damerau-Levenshtein or maybe the osa. The Wikipedia edit distance page gives a good summary.

From the stringdist package documentation:

The full Damerau-Levenshtein distance (method='dl') is like the optimal string alignment distance except that it allows for multiple edits on substrings.

The Optimal String Alignment distance (method='osa') is like the Levenshtein distance but also allows transposition of adjacent characters. Here, each substring may be edited only once. (For example, a character cannot be transposed twice to move it forward in the string).